# Content Scripts CSS doesn't overwrite the original

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My problem that I want to modify a style of a site with my custom settings. I tried with [Content Scripts](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html), but this dosent work, because they can't overwrite the original css files. Here is an example:

foo/manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["file://*/*test.html"],
      "css": ["main.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

foo/main.css

```
body {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

test.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foobar</title>
  </head>

  <body style="background:#f00;">

  </body>
</html>
```

Then i [loaded](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/getstarted.html) the the extension foo folder into my google chrome, and opened the test.html but the background color still red. I inspected the element and i saw that:

**Element Style**

`body {`
`background: #f00;`
`}`

*user stylesheet*

`body {`
    <strike>`background: #0f0;`</strike>
`}`

---

How can I modify an existing css file with my custom css with Content Scripts?
If this not possible, how can i automatically modify an existing css with my custom when page loads in google chrome specially.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An inline style rule has higher precedent over any rules imported from a stylesheet. You could use the `!important` directive to subvert this behavior:

```
body {
  background: #0f0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript, add an ID to the body tag, or some other tag that encompasses everything.  Then you can do this:

```css
// original rule
.someclass li a{
    color: blue;
}
```

```css
// your rule
#cool-extension .someclass li a{
    color: red;
}
```

If you use the original full selector, and prepend it with your ID, your rule will always take precedence.

Comment: This would require waiting for the DOM to be loaded, which may cause a [FOUC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content). A better approach could use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect when the target DOM element is loaded, and then modify its id on the fly.