# how to avoid the CSS of chrome extensions influence the style of websites

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension

when i launched my chrome extensions , its CSS style influences the style of the websites which i was visiting, is there a solution to solve the problem.

i guess maybe there was a same class or id in extension and websites, so the css conflicted！
so, what should i do with my css file to avoid the problem?

`the html in extension <div class="btn">balabala...</btn> and the html in websites <a class="btn">balabla...</a>`

```
the css file may be like this in extension file:.btn{color:red};and like this in the websites .btn{color:green};
```

Comment: its clearly an extension that is meant to alter the page... so uninstall it.

Comment: disable your extension

Comment: If you can't control the code of the extension, uninstall it. If you can control the code, add a wrapper or something with a unique ID for the extension eg. `id="myGreatExtension"`, then prefix the CSS with it to ensure it won't manipulate anything else.

Comment: Is this an extension you're writing? If so what is its purpose? Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783217/how-to-really-isolate-stylesheets-in-the-google-chrome-extension