# How to insert a panel in webpage using chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I m making an extension for gmail and trying to add a side panel when the user opens his mail( The place where contact information of the sender is shown). I searched and only found out that i can modify the css only. By modifying the css i m able to make space for the panel. Its just empty space there. How can i insert a html page in that empty space??

Comment: _"I searched and only found out that i can modify the css only"_ Well, search again. And look at [this documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12783217/934239) while you're at it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Elements panel for a variety of tasks:

```
Inspect the HTML & CSS of a web page.
Test different layouts.
Live-edit CSS.
```

To make better use of screen real estate, you may find it convenient to follow these workspace tips:

```
Collapse any panes you are not actively using.
Resize the divider between the DOM tree and the sidebar containing the panes.
```

[Ptutorial](http://www.ptutorial.com)