# How to add custom alert in Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to be able to display a styled alert (for example, add image) which the alert dialog is called from the background script of a Chrome Extension (I want to write the code of alert in `background.js`). Is there any idea how I can display the alert? Is there an APIs Chrome Extension for that?
I have a simple alert without styled :

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab){
    if(changeInfo.status == 'complete' && tab.status == 'complete'){

 alert("This is a simple alert!");

  }   });
```

Comment: Use [chrome.notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications) API

Comment: @wOxxOm I used it, but it doesn't work! the error: ` Error in event handler for tabs.onUpdated: ReferenceError: webkitNotifications is not defined`

Comment: You weren't using it because webkitNotifications is a different thing.

Comment: @wOxxOm How can I use this  chrome.notifications API ?

Comment: You can use the documentation I've linked or the [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank that works, but how can I put the notification on the center of website (change the position)?

Comment: Oh, you'll need a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that adds the corresponding DOM elements and [styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783217/how-to-really-isolate-stylesheets-in-the-google-chrome-extension). The alternative method is to open a separate window with chrome.windows.create with type: 'popup' and explicitly set position/size.