# Inject boostrap css modify the main page

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a sidebar instead to popup using chrome extension but when I inject bootstrap CSS into the sidebar the main page is modified. In this case, I tried to open the sidebar into Google page and it removes the google's icon.[image]

this is the code that i used:

```
var href = chrome.extension.getURL("/styles/bootstrap.min.css");
var inputTag = '<link id="myLink" rel="stylesheet">\n' +
'<form>' +
'<div class="well" style="height: 64px; background: white;">' +
'   <button id="editButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="float: right; color: coral; display: none">Edit</button>\n' +
'   <button id="createNewButton" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="float: right; color: coral;">New</button>\n' +
'</div>\n' +
'</form>';

var Sidebar = {

DOM_ID: "my_sidebar",
sidebar: null,
isOpen: false,

CSS_COMMON: "\
    position:fixed;\
    top:0px;\
    right:0px;\
    width:325px;\
    height:100%;\
    padding:8px;\
    background:white;\
    border-left: 2px solid #999;\
    z-index:9999999999;\
    overflow:scroll;\
",

init : function(){

},

open : function() {

    if (!Sidebar.sidebar){

        // create new sidebar
        var sidebar = document.createElement('div');
        sidebar.id = Sidebar.DOM_ID;

        Sidebar.sidebar = sidebar;
        document.body.appendChild(Sidebar.sidebar);
        var getSideBar = document.getElementById('my_sidebar');
        getSideBar.innerHTML = inputTag;
        var url = document.getElementById("myLink");
        url.setAttribute("href", href);
    }

    Sidebar.sidebar.style.cssText = Sidebar.CSS_VISIBLE;
    Sidebar.isOpen = true;

    return Sidebar.sidebar;
},
```

Could someone help me with this issue?

Comment: You're not injecting bootstrap into the sidebar, you're injecting it into the page and of course it will affect it. You could use an `<iframe>` or shadow DOM to keep things separated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783217/how-to-really-isolate-stylesheets-in-the-google-chrome-extension)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, also I used iframe before but when I put some elements on it i cannot click any element into the iframe. Do you know some suggestion for this issue?