# Do not inherit the CSS of a webpage in my chrome extension

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

Well, I am working on a chrome extension that creates a side bar (div) on the right. I have created my own CSS style file for this side bar. However, when this side bar is created on a website, it adopts the style and CSS established for such webpage. Therefore, I decided to declare an id and a class for each element in my side bar to be specific on which things I want to apply my own CSS file. I worked for a few things but most of my elements' style are overridden by the original webpage's CSS.
I tried bootstrap but it modifies the entire website and crashes my extension.
I have also tried to reset some elements with:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: initial;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    background: none;
}
```

But still not working. Does anybody know how can I apply my style sheet only to my side bar and the side bar must not inherit the style sheet of the website.

Comment: I don't think it's nicely possible, you have to set each of those css properties. Or, embed it in an iframe

Comment: you might also consider using non standard html elements like `<MySidebar>` instead of `<div id="MySidebar">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783217/how-to-really-isolate-stylesheets-in-the-google-chrome-extension)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are doing your CSS, you can override certain values by using the !important keyword. For example:

```
h1 {color: red !important}
```

Comment: Thanks! That helped me a lot. However, I have to apply this to each attribute of each element. Is there any way to apply `!important` to the whole css?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all) paired with `*` wildcard for a micro reset:

```
#yourDiv * {
    all: initial !important;
}
```

[Support is really good](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-all), especially since you're developing this extension for chrome.

`!important` may or may not be necessary.

Comment: I wouldn't target `*`, id target his sidebar

Comment: @SergChernata, thank you. It actually helped. However, if I use "all: initial !important;", it will ignore almost all the CSS I had. So I added "!important" to each attribute of CSS and I worked. I don't think this is much convenient. What would you say?

Comment: @AndresNaranjo Not at all, but that's your choice.