# Vue.js & Vuetify - is it possible to create unique css class names for all the tags?

Tags: vue.js, google-chrome-extension, vuetify.js

I want to use vuetify and vuejs as part of a chrome extension.
When importing the vuetify CSS, the problem is that it overrides the page's CSS and changes it because of CSS conflicts.
Is it possible to change the CSS and make it unique only for my application, and therefore no other page will be changed by the CSS that I use?

Comment: It's more reliable to use ShadowDOM or a special iframe, see [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12783217)

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at that. It looks like something I need. Do you know how to combine it with vuetify and vue.js?

Comment: I don't have any examples but hopefully you can find them by googling "vuetify shadowdom" or "vuetify web_accessible_resources iframe"