# Developed a Chrome extension that sent messages from context menu clicks to popup. Looking for refactoring advice

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am building a Chrome extension that add some buttons to the context menu. Upon one of the buttons being clicked, it should pass a message from the background to the popup and code in the popup should scrape the current webpage for the specified thing and save it to a firestore database. It should also display the scraped data in the popup.

The problem is that late in the project we realized that the popup code does not exist outside of when the popup is active and unless the console is active the popup closes between clicks.

Is there a way we can just inject the existing popup code into the page so it persists as a popup type thing that just sticks around?

Comment: Yes, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100953).