# Tips on Angular Routing inside a angular app that is embedded as a content script

Tags: angular, webpack, google-chrome-extension, browser-extension

We are currently developing a chrome extension written in Angular. The setup is the entire angular app is built as a content-script in manifest.json

As you can see in the code below, everything aside from `contentPage.js` is from angular source.

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*.pdf"],
      "js": ["contentPage.js", "polyfills.js", "runtime.js", "main.js"],
      "css": ["styles.css"],
      "run_at": "document_idle"
    }
  ],
```

Here comes the problem, we're having issues with routing.
Any route redirection navigates relative to the current webpage url since it is a content-script.

Let's say i'm currently at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions` then invoking `this.router.navigate(['/home'])` will navigate to `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/home`.

How do i use angular routing in the context of a chrome extension where the whole angular app is embedded as a content script?

Edit:

After investigating the issue, it seems it only doesn't work on lazy-loaded routes. The paths are correctly resolved for normal routes, but paths to lazy-loaded routes are resolved relevant to current webpage url not the chrome extension

[image: Error with lazy-loaded routes]

Comment: Such complex UI should be placed inside an iframe, see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100953).

Comment: @wOxxOm wouldn't i have any issues with routing if i use that approach?

Comment: Why? An iframe is a separate document with its own URL.

Comment: @wOxxOm, after researching for a while, can't we wrap the entire component as a Angular element or use shadow dom? Iframe to content-script communication is finicky and it would be good to know if we can use the modern alternatives.