# How to show modal pop up for extension, similar to how Honey does it?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, push-notification, notifications

I am writing a chrome extension (in React) that reminds you to stand up/sit down during the work day. After a certain amount of time has passed, the extension should give the user a notification to change postures. However, I want the user to be able to respond to the notification with a snooze or confirmation that they have changed postures.

I noticed Honey is able to show a pop up modal whenever a user is on a checkout page like so:
[image]

How do they do this? I have read that you can't programmatically pop up the extension's popup.html, so this must be using a content script to inject a popup somehow. Does anyone know how this is done?

Comment: Right-click it and inspect in devtools: you'll see a standard DOM element, which you can add in your content script. For complex UI use an iframe, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100953).