# GET chrome-extension://<chrome extension path>/<html file> net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT (anonymous) @ <back>.js:1

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I try to inject an html file using .insertAdjacentHTML

```
fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('inject.html')).then(r => r.text()).then(html => {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
  // not using innerHTML as it would break js event listeners of the page
});
```

The console returns "ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT"

[ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwbbm.png)

I have it in web-accessible resources (Manifest version 3)

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
      {
        "resources": [ "inject.html" ],
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>" ]
      }
    ],
```

I'm testing it on my own site with a simple text form.
I disabled all other chrome extensions and reloaded the page, and still, the error.

Here is a link to the repo:

https://github.com/fishsticks89/Latinizer/tree/main/src

Comment: 1) reload the extension on chrome://extensions page, 2) use `"manifest_version":3` or switch to the [old syntax of web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/web_accessible_resources/).

Comment: Both those things I have already done, although I really am considering downgrading manifest versions due to this error

Comment: Since it works for other people there must be something wrong in the other parts of code or maybe inject.html is not present in the root folder of the extension.

Comment: Here is my manifest:
https://github.com/fishsticks89/Latinizer/blob/main/src/manifest.json
and injectior.js
https://github.com/fishsticks89/Latinizer/blob/main/src/injector.js
along with the folder with all of the resources in it, including injector.js and inject.html
https://github.com/fishsticks89/Latinizer/tree/main/src

Comment: It works in Chrome 89 and newer. Note though the scripts inside inject.html won't run so it doesn't make sense to use this approach. Either include these scripts in `content_scripts` section or [use an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100953).