# VueJS app to replace page content in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome-extension

I am considering writing a **Chrome extension** in **VueJS** to totally change the apparence of a specific site.

Thus, I need to dynamically create an element, mount my VueJS app in it, and replace the body of the page with this rendered content.

I tested the dynamic creation of a container in a simple page, without Chrome extension, and it works great:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12"></script>
    <script>
      const app = new Vue({
        data: () => ({
          count: 0
        }),

        template: '<button v-on:click="count++">Clicked {{ count }} times</button>'
      });


      const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
      let vueContainer = document.createElement('div')
      body.replaceWith(vueContainer);
      app.$mount(vueContainer);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This renders the VueJS app totally OK.

But then, when I create a Chrome extension, and put the same code in my `script.js` file, it actually replaces the content of the page with a blank page. The VueJS code is interpreted (if I add a `console.log("something")` in the `mounted` method of the VueJS app, it shows up).

```
// script.js

const app = new Vue({
  data: () => ({
    count: 0
  }),

  template: '<button v-on:click="count++">Clicked {{ count }} times</button>'
});

const body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
let vueContainer = document.createElement('div')
body.replaceWith(vueContainer);
app.$mount(vueContainer);
```

```
// manifest.json

{
  "name": "My extension",
  "description": "Blah",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.mysite.fr/*"],
      "js": ["vue@2.6.12", "script.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

It's like the extension prevents the rendered content to be displayed.

Actually, when inspecting the DOM, I have the confirmation that my VueJS app **is** fired: the div is replaced… but by a HTML comment instead of the rendered content:

```
<!---->
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"vue@2.6.12"` does not look like a valid script. You should download vue bundle as a js file, put it into extension directory/package, and specify the actual correct name in `js`. If the script is fine but just the name is weird, try renaming it to .js anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your comment wOxxOm, but that's not the problem: as I said, vue@2.6.12 is loaded OK and my VueJS app is executed, hence the output in console if I had a console.log in the mounted method. Seems more like a rendering issue due to the Chrome extension?

Comment: Well, since it works in the popup, you can do the same by using `iframe` instead of `div` and rendering Vue inside that iframe, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100953).

Comment: Well, it doesn't work either :( I edited my original post after confirming the app is actually executed, the DOM is updated, but instead of getting the rendered template, is just gets a comment: `<!---->`. Hence the blank page. That's strange…

Comment: The iframe solution uses exactly the same html + scripts inside the iframe as your already working solution so it should work too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I solved it thanks to the doc. Chrome extension will block any js tags within the templates.

So the only solution is to pass a pre-compiled template.

Using **vue-cli**, then building the app to have both scripts ans tags in js files, and then referencing it in the `manifest.json` file works!