# Angular routing inside content script affects the main the current webpage

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular-routing, browser-extension

I'm currently working on a chrome extension using Angular and have a problem with routing where redirecting to certain routes actually changes the current page's URL.

Let's say you redirect to one of your app's routes `/app/testid` inside your chrome extension and you're currently inside `https://dev.to` then redirecting to route `/app/testid` will modify the current url to `https://dev.to/app/testid` w/c is the incorrect behavior.

Note:

- The angular app is inside a content script including the routing, and I'm aware that a content script can change some browser or DOM property

Comment: Put the app inside a web_accessible_resources iframe, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100953).

Comment: Thanks, but in our case its too much rewriting to do, so we decided to wrap everything inside a shadow dom