# how can I display the extension on chrome on the same page when I rigth click on the item menu (no create tab)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to display the extension when I rigth click on the custom item menu is there any way to make it , here is the code that I'm trying to pop up the popup.html.
the manifest.json look like this:

```
"background": {
      "scripts": ["eventPage.js"],
      "persistent": false
    },  
    "web_accessible_resources": [
      "popup.html"
    ],
    "permissions": [
            "storage",
            "notifications",
            "contextMenus",
            "identity.email",
            "identity"
          ],
  
    "options_page": "options.html"
```

the rigth click on the eventPage.js is the follow:

```
var menuItem = {
    "id": "HashTag",
    "title": "Create HashTag",
    "contexts": ["selection"]
};

chrome.contextMenus.create(menuItem);
//On click on the menu Item to get the function
chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (clickData) {
    copyToClipboard(clickData.selectionText);
    if (clickData.menuItemId == "HashTag" && clickData.selectionText) {

    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: The API doesn't provide a way to handle a right-click. You'll have to add a second menu item to provide additional functionality.

Comment: oh, ok but when you want to open a new tab you using this:
 chrome.tabs.create({'url': chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html')}, function(tab) {
                // Tab opened.
              });
Do you know how to display the windows on the same page? shoulde be something like  chrome something..

Comment: I didn't understand "display the windows on the same page". Could you elaborate or show a sketch?

Comment: sorry, ok when you click on here item this will display a little html named popup.html as the picture show is there any code that when you rigth click do the same as the  "click on the top item"? dont know if I explain well

Comment: 1) open a new small window, see chrome.windows.create and use `type: 'popup'`. 2) alternatively add an iframe into the page ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100953)) and make it look like the popup using CSS.

Comment: oh that create a new pop up but I just want it to open on the same page  for example emulate a click on the item in the toolbar when I do a rigth click.
"browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "img/icon16.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
in this case the popup is showing when you click on the toolbar, sorry to bother you but that is the last thing to close the sprint tks for the help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235119/discussion-between-rafa-and-woxxom).