# Chrome storage API not accessible in React based chrome extension

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I'm trying to use Chrome storage API to store access token after the user logs in the extension. However, when I try to use `chrome.storage.local` it throws error which says `local was called on undefined`.

I've added `/* global chrome */` on the top of JS file in which I want to access the storage API. But the storage is still is not accessible.

As suggested in the documentation I've the storage permission added. Also, I've already tried multiple times to reload/reinstall the extension in chrome but the problem persists.

Following is my manifest file.

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "My Extension",
"description": "This is My Extension",
"version": "1.0.0",
"homepage_url": "https://stylestash.dev",

"icons": {
"16": "ss-logo.png",
"48": "ss-logo.png",
"128": "ss-logo.png"
}, 

"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "ss-logo.png",
"default_title": "My Extension"
},


"background": {
"scripts": ["./jquery.js", "background.js"]
},
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
  "all_frames": false,
  "js": ["./content.js", "./jquery.js"],
  "run_at": "document_end"
 }
],
 "permissions": ["storage", "tabs", "activeTab", "<all_urls>"],
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
 "web_accessible_resources": ["index.html", "/static/*"]
}
```

Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You probably add your app using a `script` tag, in which case it runs in [page context](/a/9517879) where chrome.storage is undefined, which is what the error says. Instead, run your app inside an iframe, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100953) and [tutorial](https://itnext.io/create-chrome-extension-with-reactjs-using-inject-page-strategy-137650de1f39).

Comment: @wOxxOm I inject my extension inside the webpage. Hence it becomes a part of the weboage HTML document body. Do I have to inject my extension inside a iframe?

Comment: Sounds like my assumption was correct then.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks for the comments! so my only option is to use an iframe instead of a div when injecting the extension inside the webpage? Only then will I be able to the Storage API?

Comment: The only other methods: 1) use CustomEvent DOM messaging but it's not secure, 2) load react as a content script (I don't know how) instead of web_accessible_resources.