# Why ReactDOM.createPortal does not work in my content script?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, react-typescript

I have a content.tsx file with the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import {createPortal} from 'react-dom';

import Text from './Text';

console.log(`Content script...`);

createPortal(
    <Text/>,
    document.body
);
```

"Text" component code:

```
import React from 'react';

const Text = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            Just text...
        </div>
    );
};

export default Text;
```

My manifest includes:

```
...other keys
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["./static/js/content.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
]
```

As you can see, the file is loaded and the message `Content script ...` is printed in the console.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS0gK.png

But the div with the text `Just text...` was not added to the body, in other words, createPortal does not work.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2geh.png

Comment: Do it inside an iframe ([general example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100953)) e.g. with react-frame-component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to write `createPortal` inside `return` or `render`,

like this:

```js
render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
         this.props.children,
         document.body
     );
}
```

Comment: I've created an codesandbox for you, and it's working perfectly fine, can you check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-cache-2vfby?file=/src/content.jsx

Comment: I checked, the code does not work in my case, but I was able to understand the nature of my problem, thanks.