# How to prevent an element from being modified by css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm making a browser extension. It creates some UI on the page. In the UI, there are elements which are being forcefully modified by css depending on a website is opened. Aside from making it ugly, it also might break the whole UI!
The question is how to protect my poor elements from css terror?

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple options such as iframes, extremely specific classnames, and adding the `!important` field everywhere. But your best bet might be to use a [shadow DOM](https://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/) which allows for a hidden DOM tree attached to the regular (perhaps that third party website) DOM.

I've seen another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783217/how-to-really-isolate-stylesheets-in-the-google-chrome-extension) on this post that might provide more detailed answers.