# Does CSS injected by Chrome extension has less priority?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I am injecting CSS from my service_worker like this :

```
await chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    files: ['static/css/main.css'],
})
```

I see my CSS on some elements, but all elements that already have style will not be influenced by my CSS (h1, h2.. a, p, span...) even if I set `!important` to the rule...

Here is an example of my CSS :

```
.my-app h1{
    font-family: Rubik !important;
}
```

Does CSS injected by Chrome extension has less priority ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Add `origin: 'USER'` to let your `!important` win.

Comment: See also [How to really isolate stylesheets in the Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25100953)

Comment: @wOxxOm That doesn't work with [content scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/scripting/registerContentScripts), though

Comment: Well, yeah , they forgot to implement the `origin`.